how to get latest version value from multiple folders which are in s3 bucket through AWS CloudFront
if I mention the plugin version number in the url, the request will go to that version number folder in s3 bucket, but if I mention "latest" in the url, how can I identify that the request will go to latest version of folder number in s3 bucket? which configurations need to be done from CloudFront or s3 bucket?
I tried to enable static web hosting and make re-direction rule but it's not working.

Can you please share some code or explain the problem you are trying to solve?

if I mention the plugin version number in the url, the request will go to that version number folder.
but if I mention "latest" in the url, how can we identify that the request will go the latest version number of folder from s3 bucket? as s3 bucket will be having multiple numbers of folders of versioning.
